# Disappearing shiny server log

Tags: logging, digital-ocean, shiny-server

I am trying to run a Shiny app on Digital Ocean and it looks like I still have space on the machine:

```
free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         500096       78316       54188        5712      367592      385688
Swap:             0           0           0
```

This is my OS settings:

```
eliavs:/srv/shiny-server# uname -a
Linux ubuntu-eliavs 4.4.0-64-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11:50:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After trying  to connect to App I can see the log in the directory:

```
eliavs:/var/log/shiny-server# ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 shiny shiny  4096 Feb 27 08:35 .
drwxrwxrwx  8 root  syslog 4096 Feb 27 06:25 ..
-rw-r-----  1 shiny shiny   362 Feb 27 08:35 shiny-server-shiny-20170227-083550-38332.log
```

When i try to look at the log it seems like the file is not there:

```
cat shiny-server-shiny-20170227-083550-38332.log
cat: shiny-server-shiny-20170227-083550-38332.log: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu-eliavs:/var/log/shiny-server#
```

and then when i check again it is gone:

```
 ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 shiny shiny  4096 Feb 27 08:35 .
drwxrwxrwx  8 root  syslog 4096 Feb 27 06:25 ..
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am facing the same disappearing log problem too.

Comment: @chengvt no not yet can you add info on your situation maybe it will help

Comment: thanks for your reply! I resorted to debugging manually and found a library that wasn't installed so the problem was solved without looking at the disappearing log.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran into this problem yesterday after updating to shiny v1.5.3.838. I had to change the permissions on the logging directories to match the 'shiny' user.
When attempting to solve some bugs in some old apps, I noticed the log files just vanish. To fix this I added the line:

```
    preserve_logs true;
```

to the shiny-server.conf file at the top level.

This was enough for me to fix my errors and move on, so I don't know the reason why they vanish.

Comment: It seems shiny-server knows how to *make* the log file, it just doesnt know how to *keep* the logfile! Why isnt this the default anyways?

Comment: From the documentation: "Be aware that this will cause log files to accumulate very quickly on a busy server. This setting is only recommended for debugging purposes; if it were to be enabled on a production server, you would need to pay close attention to the rotation and archiving of logs to prevent your file system becoming overwhelmed with log files."

Comment: This new line should be before the "server {" line.

Comment: A little bit late. after change the conf file, shiny-server needs to be restarted: 
systemctl restart shiny-server
after that ensure that is running with:
systemctl status shiny-server

Answer (score 6):

The same thing was happening to me.  I fixed it by changing my Shiny app to be owned by the shiny server's process, i.e.

```
cd /srv/shiny-server
sudo chown -R shiny:shiny myAppFolder
```

Before I changed myAppFolder to be owned by shiny:shiny, myAppFolder was owned by root:root and I was having the disappearing log problem.  After I changed myAppFolder to be owned by shiny:shiny, the logs stopped disappearing and I was able to view them.